# loop multiple ViewBags in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am converting an asp.net project to mvc c# razor project. In the .net project, I had 2 repeater control. Now I have converted those 2 repeater functions in the controller and getting value in the ViewBag but the value I am getting separately. What I want is below -

ViewBag1 (which was Repeater 1 in .net), where values are -
Item1
Item2
Item3

ViewBag2 (which was Repeater 2 in .net), where values are -
A1
A2
B1
B2
C1
C2

How can I achieve the following by using ViewBag or Model or any other way –
Item1
      A1
      A2
Item2
      B1
      B2…..

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: output like - First Show - Item1 than next line will show A1, A2 .... like this way

Comment: `ViewBag.SomeProperty = yourRepeater1` ---- repeat for the 2nd one, just use different property name. Then in `view` just iterate over the property.

Comment: Then you need a model to represent what you want which will include properties `string Item` and `IEnumerable<string> Values` and you pass a collection of that model to the view and use nested loops to generate the output

Comment: Could you please give me an complete example, because I am new in MVC and this is my first mvc project

Comment: @ronibd, At least make an effort to try it yourself.

Comment: Hi Rob, I think I did what you said but it is given me in view All first Viewbag items and than 2nd viewbag items

Comment: repeater 1 and 2 are value of db tables

Comment: @anand, yes it is db tables vaues

Comment: use should complete details, i doubt that, give repeater 1 primary key as foriegn key in repeater 2 table, problem solved

Comment: @anand, I am using stored procedures to get data and those data is coming from different sources, I cannot do anything in database, because this is not in my control, I have to do everything in MVC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The M in MVC stands for MODEL, and the best approach is to define a datatype (Model class) that will contain your items. ViewBag is to be used with restraint, although often used for secondary data such as list items for a dropdown (and then the dropdown 'current value' is in the Model).

Something like this (very basic, expand as necessary):

**Models/Child.cs**

```
public class Child { public string Name; }
```

**Models/Parent.cs**

```
public class Parent { public string Name; public List<Child> Children; }
```

**Controllers/ParentController.cs**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var child1 = new Child { Name = "Mikey" };
    var child2 = new Child { Name = "Betsy" };
    var parent = new Parent {
        Name = "John",
        Children = new List<Child>() { child1, child2 }
    };
    return View("Index", parent);
}
```

**Views/Parent/Index.cshtml**

```
@model Your.Namespace.Parent

@* render the Model (a.k.a. the parent object) *@
<h3>Parent</h3>
<h4>@(Model.Name)</h4>

<h3>Children</h3>
@* render Model.Children = the child objects *@
@foreach (var child in Model.Children)
{
    <h4>@(child.Name)</h4>
}
```

Comment: I am getting 'Compilation Error' when I am using foreach (var child in Model.Children)

Comment: when I delete the foreach loop, I am getting different error [The model item passed into the dictionary is of type '....', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.String'.]

Comment: I just improved the **Index.cshtml** example, and tested it, this version will actually work. Just use your own namespace on the first line.

Comment: still I am getting the same compilation error, '...' does not contain a definition for 'child', but when I am compiling, did not get any error

Comment: Here is a demo solution. It was created using VS 2013 and MVC 5 + ASP.NET 4.5. It will do NuGet package restore on first build. Link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3s4HmfWgFTkN21YVExuMVl2Nkk/view?usp=sharing You can download it using small down-arrow on top.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a string data ? If so, the you will be able to split and loop through string arrays using `foreach` or `for` loop.

Store the values to Viewbags in controller, then access it   from the View.

Comment: Yes, this is a string data, I stored data in controller and used it in view, first ViewBag.LR and than ViewBag.ChildR, But its giving the all LR data first, after that all ChildR data

Comment: Refer to what @Rob Scott said. Like, ViewBag.Property1 = "data1"; ViewBag.Property2 = "data2"; -Do this from controller, and  then split them in the View.

Comment: I did the first part, then how I will split in view

Comment: Sorry for being late. You can do simple code like `string[] str1 = ViewBag.Property1.toString().Split(' '); string[] str2 = ViewBag.Property2.toString().Split(' ');` Then you get the string arrays in str1 and str2. You can loop through them as you wish.